# Is there any way to limit my Internet connection to a per program basis?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internet, debian, aptitude

My Linux connection is REALLY free.

I live in Brazil, so where I live I can only have 1 Mbit/s. Yes I know it's sad, but it's not the point.

Everytime I'm updating my Ubuntu 9.04 or downloading something, it *does* eat **all** my bandwidth. Like, while *update-manager* is downloading the packages, I can see by *netspeed applet* in my panel that the incoming traffic goes to 110 kB/s. And then, my Emesene suddenly goes disconnected, and I can't navigate.

As you can imagine, I can't use my Internet connection again until the packages are all downloaded or I cancel the update in the middle.

As I said, same thing happens when I'm dowloading something, but less intrusive and immediate.

---

The question is: is there any way to limit that APT/downloads traffic to some way I can still use my other Internet services, or to reserve some bandwidth for common navigation tasks (like we have on Windows, but I forgot this thing's name, it's like "*something* packages".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can configure apt to restrict its download speed by setting a configuration file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/, as detailed in [this post](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Debian/2008-02/msg01872.html)

Specifically, create a file:

> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/76download

that contains the text:

> Acquire { Queue-mode "access"; http { Dl-Limit "65"; }; };

where "65" is the speed in kb/s

Comment: Okay, that definitely sounds better than mine... Deleting and +1 for you.

Answer (score 15):

For other applications with no auto bandwidth control option, you can use [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle)

Example for APT with upload rate of 20 KB/s and download rate of 50 KB/s (you need sudo trickle):

> sudo trickle -u 20 -d 50 aptitude dist-upgrade

Example for wget with download rate of 30 KB/s:

> trickle -d 30 wget http://...

From trickle's man page:

> trickle is a userspace bandwidth manager.  Currently, trickle supports the shaping of any SOCK_STREAM (see socket(2)) connection established via the socket(2) interface. Furthermore, trickle will not work with statically linked executables, nor with setuid(2) executables.  trickle is highly configurable; download and upload rates can be set separately, or in an aggregate fashion.

Comment: I don't know what to do... Your post answer my question, but previous post do solve my problem. I think I'll vote for the other, but vote up your answer =]